# Question about the legendre transform in convex analysis

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

I'm work through a script about convex analysis, especially with dual problems. 
There is one step in a proof, which is not entirely clear to me.

Let $U$ be a function, which is strictly concave, $C^1$ and strictly increasing. We define

$$J(y)=\sup_{x>0}(U(x)-xy)$$

That's the Legendretransform of $-U(-x)$. One can prove that $J$ is $C^1$ too, decreasing and convex. We also have the equality:
$$J(y)=U(I(y))-yI(y)$$

where $I=-J'=(U')^{-1}$. Now, let $J_n(y)=\sup_{n\ge x>0}(U(x)-xy)$ and they claim that for $y\ge I(n)$ $J_n(y)=J(y)$. I think it should be true that for $y\le I(n)$, since:

$$J_n(y)=\sup_{n\ge x>0}(U(x)-xy)$$ and $$J(y)=U(I(y))-yI(y)$$ imply that for  $I(y)\le n$ both coincide. Or why am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are both wrong: it should be $y\ge I^{-1}(n)$.

Indeed, the formula $J(y)=U(I(y))-yI(y)$ says that the supremum in the definition of $J$ is attained at $x=I(y)$. Therefore, we get the same value $J(y)$ by taking the supremum only over $0<x\le I(y)$. In other words, 
$$J(y)=J_n(y)\quad \text{when } \  n\ge I(y)\tag1$$
Formula (1) agrees with what you wrote at the end of the post. To isolate $y$ in $n\ge I(y)$, we apply the inverse function $I^{-1}$. Since  $I$ is decreasing, the inequality changes sign:   $I^{-1}(n)\le y$.